# Embedded Elastic Search for Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch

I am trying to do some Unit as well as Integration testing for a Python API which searches from an Elastic Search. For this I am looking for an Embedded version of  Elastic search for Python 2.7 version. Could someone please point me in the correct direction ?